# How I can short my code when request have many parameters

Tags: performance, php, laravel

**Brief:**

I've create simple filter in my laravel project. I'll send parameters with ajax request.

**Code:**

```
public function specialitiesAjaxLoadMore(Request $request)
{
    $city = null;
    if(isset($request->city_id)) {
        $city = City::find($request->city_id);
        if($city !== null) {
            $city = $city->id;
        }
    }

    $sex = null;
    if((isset($request->sex) && is_numeric($request->sex)) && $request->sex == 1 || $request->sex == 2) {
        $sex = $request->sex;
    }

    $ageFrom = null;
    if((isset($request->ageFrom) && is_numeric($request->ageFrom)) && $request->ageFrom > 7) {
        $ageFrom = $request->ageFrom;
    }

    $ageTo = null;
    if((isset($request->ageTo) && is_numeric($request->ageTo)) && $request->ageTo > 7) {
        $ageTo = $request->ageTo;
    }

    if(isset($city)) {
        $candidates = Candidate::where('city_id', $city)->get();
    }

    if(isset($sex)) {
        $candidates = Candidate::where('sex', $sex)->get();
    }

    if(isset($ageFrom)) {
        $candidates = Candidate::where('birthday', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$ageFrom years")))->get();
    }

    if(isset($ageTo)) {
        $candidates = Candidate::where('birthday', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$ageTo years")))->get();
    }

    if(isset($city, $sex)) {
        $candidates = Candidate::where('city_id', $city)->where('sex', $sex)->get();
    }

    if(isset($city, $sex, $ageFrom)) {
        $candidates = Candidate::where('city_id', $city)
                               ->where('sex', $sex)
                               ->where('birthday', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$ageFrom years")))
                               ->get();
    }

    if(isset($city, $sex, $ageFrom, $ageTo) && $ageTo < $ageFrom) {
        $candidates = Candidate::where('city_id', $city)
                               ->where('sex', $sex)
                               ->where('birthday', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$ageFrom years")))
                               ->where('birthday', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$ageTo years")))
                               ->get();
    }

}
```

In my case there will be a **lot of parameters** from the request and if I continue to write everything in such a way as seisai then there will be a lot of **combinations**. So is it possible to **improve or shorten** my current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses

```
$where = [];
if($city) {
    $where[] = ['city_id', '=', $city];
}
if($sex) {
    $where[] = ['sex', '=', $sex];
}
if($ageFrom) {
    $where[] = ['birthday', '<=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$ageFrom years"))];
}
if($ageTo) {
    $where[] = ['birthday', '>=', date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$ageTo years"))];
}
$candidates = Candidate::where($where)->get();
```